# Why is $ \lim _{R \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial K(0, R)} \frac{1}{(z-b) \sin ^{2}(\pi z)} d z=0 $

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I want to show $$
\lim _{R \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\partial K(0, R)} \frac{1}{(z-b) \sin ^{2}(\pi z)} d z=0
$$

Where $\partial K(0,R)$ is the path along a circle with radius R.
It doesn't necessarily have to be along a circle, just thought it was easier to parametrize.

---

I'm trying to show that the absolute value of the integral is majorized:
$$
\lim _{R \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\partial k(0, R)} \frac{1}{|z-b|} \frac{1}{\left|\sin ^{2}(\pi z)\right|} d z 
$$

But this is a lot harder than I thought since the range of $\sin(z)$ is the entire complex plane.
Do you have some advice or tips on how to approach this problem?

Note that I don't want to use the residue theorem on this integral.

Comment: It's not true because the integrand has a pole for every integer

Comment: @NinadMunshi I believe the integral should be equal to zero, that's the purpose of the exercise, that I need to show that the residues sums to zero.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. You've asked why the limit of the integral is $0$, and I've explained why it's not. You might as well ask what is $$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-x}\tan x$$ It's not zero, either, by any stretch of the imagination. This limit does not exist.